# Hidden field value displayed in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer

Why is this field being displayed in IE?

I've look but could not find another case of this.

I am using the hidden attribute and it is still showing up...

```
<input hidden="yes" value="<?php echo $sssssssss; ?>" name="ssssssssasas"></input>
```

Comment: Surely you want `type="hidden"`, rather than `hidden="yes"`?

Comment: Ah apologies.. many hours of looking at code today has rendered me useless. Post that as an answer and I will accept :)

Comment: We've all been there ;) Glad to help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd try replacing `hidden="yes"` with `type="hidden"`.

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="hidden" value="..." name="..."></input>
```

Try in this way

Answer (score 0):

there is another choice and you can use this.

```
<div hidden> value </div> // this works in IE11
```

but also you can try,

```
display:none; // set this for the variable you want to hide and you can access its value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
<div hidden="hidden"> value </div> // this works in IE7+
```

CSS:

```
[hidden] {
   display: none;
}
```