# PHP session data changes in Internet Explorer

Tags: php, internet-explorer, session

I've defined a session to storing token using PHP like below:

```
$_SESSION['token'] = sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
```

when I want to read this session, I have not any problem in Chrome or Firefox. But in IE, it changes to something else before regenerating. For example if I store its value in a hidden field of form and submit it like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['token']; ?>" />
```

I will get this result in IE in the next page:

```
echo $_SESSION['token']; // shows 1b05fab5ec11f1d50713aea6e74f84727d29b4a3
echo $_POST['token']; // shows e8fac6d55b04d1752f37ecde953f7f08b112ccca
```

Whereas if I print `$_SESSION['token']` immediately after creation or even in end of its creation page, it shows the content exactly and with no problem.

What is this problem for ?

**Edit:**
This is my form :

```
<form action="process/login.php" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['token']; ?>" />
   <label>Email: </label><input type="text" name="email" />
   <div class="space"></div>
   <label>Password: </label><input type="password" name="password" />
   <div class="space"></div>
   <input type="submit" value="Login" class="button" />
</form>
```

Comment: Did you check if cookie are enabled on IE ? =/

Comment: Show us the code that puts the token in the POST data

Comment: Did you try to name the $_SESSION['token'] to something else ? In example try $_SESSION['my_app_token']. This way you will be sure that there is no conflict with other app/script.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12266811/hidden-field-value-displayed-in-ie check this link out.

Comment: Is the page inside iframe?

Comment: Do you have another input called token? This has happened to me before, so thought I'd ask. Also check if all the html are correctly formed by running the page through a validator. Firefox and chrome tends to be lot more forgiving. http://validator.w3.org/ Lastly, to rule out some strange local IE config/plugin issue, can you replicate this in another computer?

Comment: Did you change from HTTP and HTTPS somewhere?

Comment: @func0der, no I did not

Comment: Did you try another dev environment? I mean another server? Just to complete the tests. ^^

Comment: I couldn't find any mentioning of the browser version. What IE version are you using and have you tried it with other versions?

Comment: And another thing. Is the form's target the same page or a different one?

Comment: @Gil, it is IE9. I did not test it on other versions of IE. For your next question, I have to say target is not same.

Comment: Set your browser mode to IE8 and see if it's still happening.

Comment: Yes it happens in IE8 mode too

Comment: In that case... I didn't want to bring this up because it seems there was no need, but I'm out of ideas at this point :) . When you check it with IE, is there another tab opened on the site at the same time?

Comment: No it is one tab only

Comment: @MohammadBagherSaberi What do you mean the target is not the same? you mean you have `<form action='something' method='post' target='something_else>`?

Comment: @nl-x in the 5 previous comments, Gil asked me about it. I meant the target file (action) ...

Comment: as implied by the question of @MikaTuupola, iframes can cause problems with cookies in IE if the [P3P policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P3P) is not specified

Comment: @WalterTross there is no IFrame in my project

Answer (score 4):

Since PHP and session storage are server side and IE is obviously a client, the problem does not reside in your session code.

Sessions are usually kept track of by a cookie (session cookie) or though a POST/GET variable. By default in PHP this value is named PHPSESSID.

Probably, in your case either the session cookie or POST/GET variable that is linked to your server side session is not coming over okay in IE. In case of a cookie, it might have to do with cookie settings and whether or not cookies are allowed at all. In case of a POST/GET it could be that your HTML is malformed in a way that IE doesn't like, but other browser do understand.

Now once that value is lost in IE, PHP assigns that browser a new session on each request, and the session token is regenerated on each request. But your hidden field remembers the old token as well...

If you show us more code (you can edit your question), I can edit my answer to give you more details.

**edit**
You can start by showing us the relevant php.ini settings lines that concern sessions and session cookies. And by double checking your IE cookie settings. In specific I would like to know if you have set a cookie_path, making cookies only available in the same directory.

Maybe you even have an IE security setting or add-on installed preventing cookies. So try checking your IE settings and disable all add-ons and test it again.

Also check if the first page (that sets the session) and the second page (that reads the session) have EXACTLY the same domain name.

So for example `www.yourdomain.com` in the first page, should not be `yourdomain.com` on the second page (without the www) or `www.yourdomain.com.` (with an extra dot at the end).

Comment: thank you for your attention.
There is no problem with sessions and cookies. I've created another session `$_SESSION['test']=123`, and it had not any problem in the same senario. When I posted it, its value was equal with session value.

Comment: Yes but since `123` is a fixed string you don't know if it is being overwritten by itsself on you second request. I'm 95% convinced it's a cookie problem... Try using the element inspector in FF/Chrome and F12 developer tools in IE to view the cookies. You will probably not see them in IE, or see a different value each time.

Comment: in php.ini, I have this: `session.cookie_path = /`. First page and second page are in the same path. Also I have not any special add-ons in IE

Comment: you have stopped answering!

Comment: @MohammadBagherSaberi The cookie settings seem to be okay. What a good follow up might be is the following: Go to your site in Firefox (FF) and Internet Explorer (IE). And open Element Inspector in FF and Developer tools in IE. You can open them both by hitting the F12 key on your keyboard while in the browser. In both of them go to the Network tab. Now refresh and look at the request headers of the load of your page. (Ignore image requests etc.) Pay special attention to the cookie or POST parameter called PHPSESSID. ... Then go to your second page, and look for the same cookie/POST parameter.

Comment: What you want to do now is make sure the PHPSESSID of the two pages stays the same. So tell me if the PHPSESSID value is changing every time. And if so, try to figure out why that is. You can try copy/paste here the entire Cookie line, from the request headers, as well as the complete Request URL.

Comment: PHPSESSID is same in first and second page. Both in IE and FF

Comment: Wow... Okay. Please show us more (the entire?) code ... especially the `<form>...</from>` part. Maybe there's a problem there. You do have `<form method='post' action='something...'>...</form>`, right?

Comment: @MohammadBagherSaberi Nothing fancy here yet. Please show MORE code. Try showing the code that sets the session and the token. (Maybe show the entire code via pastebin?) Also please tell ... In FF and IE, when using the Element Inspector and Developer tools. How many requests were there on each side for loading the first and second page. (Talking only about the php page, not the images and other resources. How many redirects were involved?)

Comment: I'm facing same exact issue, But for me it only happens when i logged into Site1 and accessing site2.

Answer (score 2):

I think after your form submits you might be creating another token value.

use

```
if(!isset($_POST['token'])){
  $_SESSION['token'] = sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
}
```

Comment: If it were that, it wouldn't work for the OP on chrome or firefox I guess, he said that the problem is IE specific.

Comment: replace type="hidden" with hidden="yes"

Comment: @ViswanathPolaki your answer will end up with OP having no $_SESSION['token'] anymore on the second or third page request. And your comment above is really silly as that is not legal in HTML, and will make the hidden field become visible.

Answer (score 1):

I would try changing the name of the input to something else, maybe IE is doing some weird stuff with the token name. Searched the net, but nothing mentions this, but just to be on safe side, and remove this option I would do it.

```
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['token']; ?>" />
```

to:

```
<input type="hidden" name="my_session_token" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['token']; ?>" />
```

And try changing `$_SESSION['token']` to `$_SESSION['my_session_token']` as stated above in a comment

Comment: did you try to change the `$_SESSION['token']` to something else like `$_SESSION['my_session_token']`??

Comment: Since OP is getting ***some*** value for $_POST['token'] in all browsers, this name of the value is obviously not the problem.

Comment: @nl-x Since the OP tested with a `$_SESSION['test']` and it worked fine, then I couldn't think of anything other than a naming issue.

Comment: @CodeBird I'm not 100% sure. But since the test OP did was with a fixed string `123`, it doen't prove anything, I'm afraid. Maybe OP would like to do with `$_SESSION['test']=sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));` and `<input type="hidden" name="test" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['test']; ?>" />` to rule this out?

Comment: @nl-x Yes I think that's what he should do, just to make sure that simple stuff are working. I mean I always prefer testing simple stuff before going into more complicated stuff

Answer (score 1):

I'm almost certain that you are assigning the `$_SESSION['token']` twice. It might be the same line of code being executed twice or you've assigned the variable somewhere else too. In order to find the problem you need to define a function as a wrapper for assigning the session entry. Then call the function instead of assigning the variable directly. Here's the sample code:

```
function assign_token()
{
    $_SESSION['token'] = sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
}
```

But you need to make sure never assign the `token` directly anywhere within your code. And call this function instead. Once you've done this, if you have a debugger, all you need to do is to set a break point within this function and see how many times it is called and from where.

But in case you don't have a debugger installed, or even worse, in case the assignment happens not within a single request but in two, you need to modify your function like this:

```
function assign_token()
{
    file_put_contents('/tmp/assign_token.txt', time() ."\n". print_r(debug_backtrace(), true), FILE_APPEND);
    $_SESSION['token'] = sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
}
```

The line added will help you track each time the function is called. Even if it's called twice within two separate requests, you can identify them thanks to `FILE_APPEND` and `time()`. The first one appends to the file (obviously) so log entries won't overwrite each other and second one helps knowing if two entries of your log are made in the same request.

That's all I've got. At the end, you may want to style the log entries making them more readable.

Comment: I don't create `$_SESSION["token"]` twice. If your idea was correct, I had to see the problem in other browsers like FF and Chrome too.

Comment: Not necessary. Maybe the second request which updates the session is sent only in IE! If I were you, I would consider the possibility before going on to deeper levels.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something more along the lines of this:

```
md5(uniqid($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], true))
```

Assuring that the token will always be unique.

Comment: Really a bad idea. Easily hackable. And still doens't explain why the problem exists.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if i'm wrong but i've tested already code below in Chrome FF and IE 7 and it doesn't seems that there is any issue with IE.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" action="/">
            <?php
            session_start();
            if(!$_SESSION['token']){
                $_SESSION['token'] = sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
            }
            ?>
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['token']; ?>" name="token"/>
            <button type="submit" name="send">Send</button>
            <?php
            if(!empty($_POST)){
                var_dump($_POST);
                var_dump($_SESSION['token']);
            }
            ?>
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

If You have php version >= 5.4 try to set builtin server in php with this command ():

```
php -S localhost:88 -t /path/to/your/app
```

Assume that You are testing in your local computer. Mayby something is wrong with apache+php stack on your server.

Comment: I fail to see how this would change anything

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of the **sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true))**. IE has problems with names that contain '-' or '_' - they cannot maintain a session! I've had this problem twice in the past, and it always takes me weeks to figure out, and I'm shocked IE hasn't fixed it.

Just make sure you don't have such characters!

Comment: The sha1 is not a name... It's a value