# PHP session value changes unwanted on remote server in some browsers

Tags: php, session, token, csrf

Unfortunately because I could not find the appropriate answer for my asked question [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22115825/php-session-data-changes-in-internet-explorer), I had to ask it again.
I must prevent CSRF attacks in my web application. So I created a token in top of the main file **index.php** like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['token'] = md5(uniqid());
?>
```

And put it in a hidden field of forms to send it to processing files like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['token']; ?>" />
```

When I run the codes in the processing files locally, everything is Ok and both **$_POST['token']** and **$_SESSION['token']** are same as each other. I made myself sure with running the code below:

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['token'].'<br />'.$_POST['token'];
// Out put is like lines below:
// 7cf64efc6f8ad5bdf9c04e57feb7d1f9
// 7cf64efc6f8ad5bdf9c04e57feb7d1f9
?>
```

I expected it must work with same manner when I upload the project on remote host. But it has a strange behavior on the Internet. **$_POST['token']** and **$_SESSION['token']** are not same as each other anymore on the web. **$_SESSION['token']** changes in the processing file without any recreation code!

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['token'].'<br />'.$_POST['token'];
// Out put is like lines below:
// 22a0331a5ef07b96d95e2e0f6b98e282
// f859cc725cf7c7026aaaf84a48779199
?>
```

The stranger point is that this unknown manner was in IE before, but now it does not occur in IE, and this time it happens in Chrome. Firefox does not have this problem too.

I don't know what is the matter. Nobody could help me with an appropriate answer.
Please help me ...

Comment: I think your session was reset, can you post your code exactly?

Comment: If you think correctly, why it does not occur in all browsers?

Comment: You don't have any proof to show us this? so that we can consider this as correct, and re-check your code, also, no one else reporting same issue.

Comment: I can write all of the codes here. But they are many lines of codes. I have written what was important for this question.

Comment: can you provide just relevance code?

Comment: Dear @JasonOOO, everything is the codes I have witten in the question. If you want to make sure that there is not any missing point, I have created a simple instance of it in http://www.bbtravel.ir/test/test.php. Try it in different browsers

Comment: can you provide the code in these files also?

Comment: check this out, it might be, somehow, related https://secure.kitserve.org.uk/content/php-session-cookie-problems-google-chrome-and-internet-explorer

Comment: Well have you at least checked whether or not the session id stays the same …?

Comment: @CBroe yes session id is same. You can look at http://www.bbtravel.ir/test/test.php

Comment: I suspect your issue as per the answer by the guy below lies with the fact it generates a new ID for each new page for the session token

Comment: @Adsy2010, so why I have not this problem on local machine ?

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a huge part in creating and checking the tokens. The problem here lies on the line `$_SESSION['token'] = md5(uniqid());`. At least wrap it to something like this,

```
if ( isset ( $_SESSION['token'] ) ) {
    $_SESSION['token'] = md5(uniqid());
}
```

Then after validation and usage, you can freely change the token again.

Comment: Creating token session occurs only once, on top of index.php. There are not any other place to create it

Comment: Yes, that may be the case but you need to check it if it exists or has been used. Otherwise you'll be creating a different token every request.